# How to disable network connectivity dynamically for a process?

Tags: android

My app is data intensive and I want to provide users the comfort of turning on/off WIFI only data usage.

My application makes use of the network connectivity all over and also the ads do too.  How can I globally for the app process limit the data connectivity type to only WIFI?

Answer (score 0):

If wifi is enabled, then the phone uses it instead of cell networks.

You can check if it is enabled using `WifiManager`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#isWifiEnabled%28%29 and decide based on that boolean wether you use the network or not.

You can also check `getConnectionInfo ()` to make sure that a connection is active: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html

Comment: Thanks  for your reply.  However this is kinda what I didn't want to do, check every time I need to connect to the internet if WIFI connected or not.  I thought maybe there would be a flag or something that can disable internet connection to the process.  I would than have a BroadcastReceiver and every time the connection changes I enable or dissable network connectivity for the process.

Comment: @Moto Take a look at these two posts. They implemented a BroadcastReceiver as the one you're asking for: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/monitor-wifi-status-and-information.html and https://thiranjith.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/how-to-monitor-network-connectivity-in-android/

Comment: Thanks that's actually great information. Again not really what I'm looking for but this definitely provides better tools to resolve this issue.  The mayor question is how to disable network connectivity to a process?